# Change drive letter for .lnk-shortcuts with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, data-manipulation, shortcut

I got multiple Windows shortcuts that target another drive than the one I use now. I want to copy all the shortcuts and change the "target-value" for these files.

Example:

file name: Movie-Trainspotting.lnk

file place: D:\MovieVault

target: "**A**:\Movies\Movie-Trainspotting.avi"

open in: "**A**:\Movies"

My goal is to find a way to replace the letter **A** with example H.
Keep in mind that I got many files which needs this, I would prefer a for each loop that target all the files in a specific folder (txtbSti.Text)

Is there a way to do this, as simple as possible?

Comment: Have a look ar [Edit shortcuts .lnk properties with C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/44329/Edit-shortcuts-lnk-properties-with-C). Also [How to get the target of a windows shortcut C#](https://astoundingprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/how-to-get-the-target-of-a-windows-shortcut-c/) - you may find ways to **set** also

Comment: I Think the simplest way to do that is to change the drive letter of the new drive from H to A, using Disk Managment (Tutorial: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-a-drive-letter-2626069), but if you can't or don't want to do that, tell me and i will help you do it using vb.net.